# Blog System - elements overlapping

Tags: php, html, css

I'm making a simple blog service.

I'm going to be using a form and PHP to append each new entry to the file that contains all of my blog entries, which will be loaded onto my main page.

How it looks now:

### [image: Current Situation]

HTML:

```
<p class="title">Blog Post</p><br>
<pre class="body">
This is a long entry, full of lots of random gibberish that ultimately makes absolutely no sense.
I like cats, dogs, ostriches and peanut butter, combined that makes a Cadostrichutterpea,
and that's one amazing creature, if you ever come across one, take a picture for me.

If you manage to get me that picture i'll thank you a thousand times over, because i have
trouble putting my imaginations onto paper.
</pre>

<p class="title">Small Blog Post</p><br>
<pre class="body">
A Cadostrichutterpea was spotted today in Thailand.
</pre>

<p class="title">Blog Post</p><br>
<pre class="body">
This is a long entry, full of lots of random gibberish that ultimately makes absolutely no sense.
I like cats, dogs, ostriches and peanut butter, combined that makes a Cadostrichutterpea,
and that's one amazing creature, if you ever come across one, take a picture for me.

If you manage to get me that picture i'll thank you a thousand times over, because i have
trouble putting my imaginations onto paper.
</pre>
```

CSS:

```
p.title
{
    overflow: auto;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    width: 500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background-size: 1px 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: bold;
    line-height:100%;
}
pre
{
    width: 500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: rgb(103, 103, 103);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    line-height:100%;
}
```

---

How I want it to look:

### [image: Ideal Look]

I'm just not sure how to make it so that the `p`/`pre` elements stack with each other rather than layer up.

I could add a load of line breaks and try and use PHP to determine how many breaks I'll need depending on the length of the entry.

Is there a be a better way of doing this?

When I hard coded the positions to see how it would look, when I scrolled down the page all the elements scrolled as well, so you couldn't see more elements than fit the screen, is there a way I can stop that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are positioning all your elements with `position: fixed;` this is why they are layered on top of each other and wont scroll as expected.

Try removing `position: fixed;`.

See this ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/054eoa3e/)***.

I also removed the `<br>` elements after your `<p>` titles since those are not needed. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for more information on positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all occurrences of `position:fixed`.

Before:

```css
p.title
{
    overflow: auto;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    width: 500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background-size: 1px 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: bold;
    line-height:100%;
}
pre
{
    width: 500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: rgb(103, 103, 103);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    line-height:100%;
}
```

```html
   <p class="title">Blog Post</p><br>
    <pre class="body">
    This is a long entry, full of lots of random gibberish that ultimately makes absolutely no sense.
    I like cats, dogs, ostriches and peanut butter, combined that makes a Cadostrichutterpea,
    and that's one amazing creature, if you ever come across one, take a picture for me.
    
    If you manage to get me that picture i'll thank you a thousand times over, because i have
    trouble putting my imaginations onto paper.
    </pre>
    
    <p class="title">Small Blog Post</p><br>
    <pre class="body">
    A Cadostrichutterpea was spotted today in Thailand.
    </pre>
    
    <p class="title">Blog Post</p><br>
    <pre class="body">
    This is a long entry, full of lots of random gibberish that ultimately makes absolutely no sense.
    I like cats, dogs, ostriches and peanut butter, combined that makes a Cadostrichutterpea,
    and that's one amazing creature, if you ever come across one, take a picture for me.
    
    If you manage to get me that picture i'll thank you a thousand times over, because i have
    trouble putting my imaginations onto paper.
    </pre>
```

After:

```css
p.title
{
    overflow: auto;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    width: 500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background-size: 1px 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: bold;
    line-height:100%;
}
pre
{
    width: 500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: rgb(103, 103, 103);
    left: 0; right: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    line-height:100%;
}
```

```html
   <p class="title">Blog Post</p><br>
    <pre class="body">
    This is a long entry, full of lots of random gibberish that ultimately makes absolutely no sense.
    I like cats, dogs, ostriches and peanut butter, combined that makes a Cadostrichutterpea,
    and that's one amazing creature, if you ever come across one, take a picture for me.
    
    If you manage to get me that picture i'll thank you a thousand times over, because i have
    trouble putting my imaginations onto paper.
    </pre>
    
    <p class="title">Small Blog Post</p><br>
    <pre class="body">
    A Cadostrichutterpea was spotted today in Thailand.
    </pre>
    
    <p class="title">Blog Post</p><br>
    <pre class="body">
    This is a long entry, full of lots of random gibberish that ultimately makes absolutely no sense.
    I like cats, dogs, ostriches and peanut butter, combined that makes a Cadostrichutterpea,
    and that's one amazing creature, if you ever come across one, take a picture for me.
    
    If you manage to get me that picture i'll thank you a thousand times over, because i have
    trouble putting my imaginations onto paper.
    </pre>
```